# elastic search get bucket count

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query:

```
GET images/_search
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "term":{
                  "appID.raw":"myApp"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{
      "perDeviceAggregation":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"deviceID",
            "min_doc_count":50000
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This query returns a "buckets" array, but I would like to return only the length of the array, without the array itself.

Explanation: the purpose of this query is to count how many devices that belong to app "myApp", have over 50,000 images. I don't need the query to return these devices, just to know how many are there.

Answer (score 0):

The [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) returns buckets -- 1 bucket for each unique term of the field -- where each bucket contains the *count* of documents that contain the term.

It sounds like you want to know the *number of unique terms* instead of the document count per term. This concept is called `cardinality`.

There is a [different aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) to determine cardinality. Your query would look like this:

```
GET images/_search
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "term":{
                  "appID.raw":"myApp"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{
      "deviceIdCardinality":{
         "cardinality":{
            "field":"deviceID"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**NOTE:** cardinality counts are approximate. You can configure the accuracy with the `precision_threshold` parameter to the aggregation. See the documentation for specifics.

Comment: I'm not sure this query is what I need, because I wanted to count the number of users who have a number of images above a certain threshold.

Comment: Can you update your question to ask what you actually want? With sample data? And what you expect as a result? I don't see anything about users or images in the json in your question.

Comment: perhaps we can chat about it in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125929/discussion-elasticsearch-field-counting?

Comment: No, he said he wants the amounts of bucket, which is literally the total amount of results. It's unexplainable to me too why Elasticsearch doesnt deliver this out of the box